# How to fetch Django related model rows and return as a list of dictionary?

Tags: python, django

AM using Django v1.11

I have the following models:

```
class LineItem():
    quote = models.ForeignKey(Quote, related_name="quote_line_items")
    sku = models.ForeignKey(SKU)

class Quote():

     def fetch_as_list_of_dict(self):
         return LineItem.objects.filter(quote=self).select_related('sku__product').values()

class SKU():
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
```

My `fetch_as_list_of_dict` fails to contain the sku.product_id or sku.product object. I only need to get the sku.product_id as part of a dictionary which in itself is one of many in a list.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Your models won't work. They don't inherit from `Model` and `Quote` and `SKU` are referenced before being defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it by:

```
def fetch_as_list_of_dict(self):
     return self.listitem_set.select_related('sku__product').values('sku__product')  # or any fields like sku__product__name, sku__product__id anything
```

Please check [related object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/) documentation for more details on fetching related object.

Comment: Thanks! Happy holidays to you @ruddra. I appreciate you helping me again :)

Answer (score 0):

The code seems correct, there's one thing you can do -
Change self to self.pk as below

```
def fetch_as_list_of_dict(self):
     return LineItem.objects.filter(quote=self.pk).select_related('sku__product').values()
```

Second way -
Try to get SKU object only first.

```
def fetch_as_list_of_dict(self):
     return LineItem.objects.filter(quote=self).select_related('sku__product')
```